# Data Cleanse: Grouping within variable company names

Tags: python, sas, stata

So working on some research on nursing homes which are often owned by a chain. We have a list of 9,000 + nursing homes corporate ownership. Now, if I was MERGING this data into anything I think this would not be too much of a challenge, but I am being asked to group the facilities that are associated with each other for another analysis. 
For example:
ABCM
ABCM CORP
ABCM CORPORATION
ABCM CORPORATE

I have already removed all the extra spaces, non-alphanumeric, and upcased everything. Just trying to think of a way within like a 90% accuracy I can do this. The within the same variable is the part that is throwing me off. I do have some other details such as ownership, state, zip, etc. I use STATA, SAS, and Python if that helps!

Comment: Try the fuzzy matching functions of sas, like edit distance.

Answer (score 1):

welcome to SO.

String matching is - broadly speaking - a pain, whatever the software you are using, and in most cases need a human intervention to yield satisfactory results.

In Stata you may want to try `matchit` (`ssc install matchit`) for fuzzy string merge. I won't go into the details (I suggest you to look at the helpfile, which is pretty well-outlined), but the command returns each string matched with multiple similar entries - where "similar" depends on the chosen method, and you can specify a threshold for the level of similarities kept or discarded.

Even with all the above options, though, the final step is up to you: my personal experience tells me that no matter how restrictive you are, you'll always end up with several "false positives" that you'll have to work yourself!

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I did implement Matchit in Stata before coming here, but the results had a lot of false positives. Ultimately I am biting the bullet and reducing duplicate entries as much as possible by getting rid of all non-alphanumeric characters, deduping, etc. That reduced to 3,000 names which I am just going to have to slog through. Thank you for the suggestion!